# servicestack sql server keyword not supported ormlite

Tags: azure-sql-database, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm using servicestack in an api c# project and have referenced the

- servicestack.ormlite
- servicestack.ormlite.sqlserver

nuget packages.

I can connect to sql server as expected.

We are now trying to implement Always Encrypted colums in some of our sql server table columns.  We append the following to our db connection strings:

";Column Encryption Setting=Enabled"

When running this line is c#:

`var id = await Db.InsertAsync(customer, selectIdentity: true);`

an exception is now raised:

`"Keyword not supported: 'column encryption setting'."`

This is probably because Always Encrypted isn't supported within the Ormlite package.  Is there a way of implementing something similar with ServiceStack?

Comment: I've also tried using the servicestack.ormlite.sqlserver.data package (which i think has a reference to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient which does support Always Encrypted), but this still doesn't work (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/sqlclient-support-always-encrypted?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an OrmLite error, it's [coming from the System.Data.SqlClient](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/390) ADO.NET Provider.

You'd need to use the [ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer.Data](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer.Data) package which  does reference the **Microsoft.Data.SqlClient** pacakge as suggested by the [.NET Core reported Issue](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/390#issuecomment-576359956).

[image]

Which the decompiled sources shows us does reference the **Microsoft.Data.SqlClient** namespace:

[image]

If that doesn't work, see if you can open a connection directly with the **Microsoft.Data.SqlClient** SqlConnection class, e.g:

```
var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
conn.Open();
```